# Command prompt switches to >, what does this indicate ?

Tags: command-line

Sometime I have observed that when I type a character at the command prompt such as the one shown below I get a > .

```
root@ubuntu:/home/heena# \
>
```

I observed even the following works fine:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/heena# \
> ls
```

But what is this actually?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [POSIX specification for the Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html), if a newline follows a backslash character (`\`), the shell shall interpret this as a line continuation, i.e. the shell will interpret the next line as if it would be part of the first. This is an exception to the usual meaning of `\`, which is escapes the following character, preserving its literal value. The `>` indicates that the input will be treated as such a line continuation.

This also occurs with unbalanced single or double quotes (`'`, `"`), which preserve the literal value of each character within the quotes (with some exceptions regarding `"`). In this case, the newline between the quotes is interpreted as part of the input, and will not trigger the parsing of the command line.

Comment: It will also show for incomplete conditional and loop statements.

Answer (score 2):

This is `$PS2` or second-level prompt which indicates a continuation of the previous line(s). It also shows if you have unbalanced single or double quotes.